# Sum of cosines in given interval

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the sum $C(j,k) := cos\left(\frac{j \pi}{n}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)$ where $j$ and $k$ range from $1$ to $n$ (independently) for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For given $a,b \in [-2,2]$, is there known how many pairs $(j,k)$ exist, such that $C(j,k) \in [a,b]$?

What I want is a formula (or an estimate) for any $a,b$ without having to compute the values first. I am most interested in the intervals $[-1,0]$ and $[1/2,2]$.

Comment: Shouldnt the ordered pairs be $[j,k]$ raher than $i$??

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited that

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want a method, by which you can calculate the count for any $a,b$? What about calculating all the $C(j,k)$ values in sorted order?

Comment: @Aravind: I just made an edit to clarify the question